# Footer is not in the bottom of the window, (phonegap jquery mobile app for windows mobile)

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

I am developing a windows mobile app using jquery and phonegap. I have put footer for the app.

```
            <div class="footer" ></div>
```

It is properly showing in IE browser. But it is showing in the simulator little bit up from the bottom of the window.

Comment: what kind of question is this. Oh my God. care to share the CSS?

Answer (score 4):

The question is tagged with jquery-mobile. So I assume you are using jQuery mobile.

Why don't you use jQuery mobile footer, `<div data-role="footer">`?

Then you achieve this by adding `data-postion="fixed"` attribute, i. e.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```

Find more here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/fixed-toolbars/

Answer (score 3):

The problem with fixed positioning of an element at the very bottom of a portrait view of a PhoneGap app for Windows Phone is that the browser control will by default leave an empty space to allow for the address bar (despite the `bottom: 0px` CSS attribute).

After looking left and right for a solution I was successful bringing my footer to the very bottom of the screen in both portrait and landscape modes using media queries and -ms-viewport rule like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  @-ms-viewport       { width: 320px!important; height:device-heigth!important; }
}
@media screen and (min-height: 320px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  @-ms-viewport       { width:auto!important; height:320px!important; }
}
```

The change that actually brings the footer down in portrait mode is setting the `heigth:device-height!important`. However, doing so apparently invalidates other default viewport settings which results in any text on the page appearing very small. In order to make the text readable, you must also explicitly set the width, which I am setting to 320px in the example above - you can choose a setting that works for you.

Comment: The footer on my application wasn't on extreme bottom only on Windows phone Emulator.
The solution informed by @Tomasz Janczuk worked nice. However, does not work on real device, only on emulator.
Thanks Tomasz

Answer (score 1):

If data-position="fixed" does not work then remove data-position="fixed" from the footer div and try following,

```
.ui-footer{
    bottom: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    z-index: 10000; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 2.5em; 
    position: fixed; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

(also try by adding !important to bottom, margin-bottom)

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer{
        bottom:0px !important;
        position:absolute !important;
        width:100% !important;
 }
```

this fixed the footer issue for me on Windows Phone 8. Now its at the bottom of the page

Comment: You've to do it with javascript, when the keyboard is down (focus out), change the position to fixed.